# Which test should I use to compare three geometric means?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mean, geometric-mean

I'm trying to use some test to compare three geometric means of some dataset, to see if there are significant differences. I want to compare A with B, B with C and A with C, but I'm unsure of which test I should use.
I'm thinking about some t-test, but with some twist. I have been searching for info but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: More information will be needed. Note that geometric means only make much sense for positive random variables (in particular a normal model won't be suitable since it gives probability to negative values). 1. What is your distributional model? 2. What's the null (and alternative) hypothesis? ... keeping in mind that hypotheses are statements about populations rather than samples. - - - Alternatively it may be possible to construct a nonparametric test (permutation test) or a bootstrap test if a suitable statistic is identified.

Comment: Assuming you have positive random variables, geometric mean is exponentiated mean of arithmetic mean. So you can use tests for means, on log-transformed data.