# Kruskal Wallis test or ANOVA for G-mean?

Tags: anova, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kruskal-wallis-test, bonferroni, geometric-mean

I currently working on the data (4 groups), which requires the evaluation in Geometric means.
I transform the data into logarithms (which is non-normal distributed), then I wonder whether to use ANOVA or KW test?

My colleague insists that I should separate the data into pairs and use the Mann-Whitney test instead. However, neither of us is an expert in statistics. So, I don't know what to do.

P.S. I also want to know how to pick adjustment methods such as LSD, Bonferroni, Sidak, etc.

Comment: You're offering options [that you think will solve your problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) without properly explaining the problem or its context. 1. It's unclear how geometric means come into it -- you should clarify; why would four groups *require* a geometric mean? What is the context? 2. When you say "require the evaluation of", what are you trying to do?  3. I suspect you may well want something different from all the options you consider but so little is explained about the problem you're trying to solve that any suggestions would be guesses.

Comment: For example, it's not clear that you have a testing problem at all. If you do, it's not clear what the hypothesis is nor how it would relate to the geometric means you mention.

Comment: @Glen_b I want to report the level of antibodies stimulated by 4 medicines, therefore 4 groups of populations. Several previous publications reported using G means, but I am not sure how they compare between groups. I used KW but my colleagues suggested that I have to use MW instead.

Comment: KW is a viable choice and a perfect multiplicity adjustment is self-contained in it.  It tests a more general hypothesis related to whether any of the 4 groups have values that tend (in the population) to be larger than values in any of the 3 remaining groups.

Comment: To address one piece:  I would recommend against the advice to use pairwise Mann-Whitney tests.  One problem with this approach is that it looks only at two groups at a time, and ignores the rest of the data for each iteration.  It is better to use a test designed for multiple groups, like the Dunn test (1964), which is usually used as post-hoc test following a Kruskal-Wallis test. ...  I would be curious to know why your colleague thinks it is better to use pairwise MW tests rather than a KW test.

Comment: Also, if your goal is to compare geometric means, use an approach that compares among geometric means.  Kruskal-Wallis will not (usually) compare means.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thank you for your answer. This would be helpful :)

Comment: @SalMangiafico Thank you for your answer. Actually, I argued with my colleague. I am almost certain that I must work with KW. But, neither of us is a statistician, so I have to find the reason (rather than I know from cross-work) to convince him. With your information, I think I can build up my case against him. Thank you a lot for your advice.

Comment: Why work with Kruskal-Wallis when you are interested in the geometric means ?  Why not use a method that compares geometric means ?  There are a few comments on comparing geometric means here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/395411/which-test-should-i-use-to-compare-three-geometric-means .